# How do i prevent the session id being passed between client and server via URL query string?

Tags: jsf, query-string, session-cookies, web.xml, jsessionid

How do i prevent the session id being passed between client and server via URL query string?
I dont want the session identifier to be passed over the URL query string. How do i ensure this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Praveenkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure how your container tracks the session using your web.xml. Just add this to enforce cookies:

```
<session-config>
  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

But please not that if you force your container to use cookies, you will break session handling for users that don't have cookies enabled.